# How to write a text and then press enter and a jbutton activates

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, enter

I have a Jtextfield where i write a result inside.Then i want to press enter while my cursor is in the jtextfield,and activate a jbutton named next.I had to my constructor this command:"getRootPane().setDefaultButton(next);",and work well.After i change from desing the font from all the jbuttons and jlabels and then when i writting i jtextfield and press enter nothing happened.

```
public class PrakseisGameGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {



int correctAns;
int allAns;
int oldResult;
int flag;

public PrakseisGameGUI() {

    initComponents();

    getRootPane().setDefaultButton(next);
    Global.correctAns = 0;
    Global.allAns = 0;
    oldResult = -500;
    flag = 0;
 }

 /**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String sResult;
    String sCorAns;
    String sAllAns;
    String sOperator;


    int iFirstNum = 0;
    int iSecNum = 0;
    int iOperator = 0;
    int iResult = 0;
    int iCorResult = 0;
    int oldFirstNum = 0;
    int oldSecNum = 0;
    int oldOperator = 0;

    Random rand = new Random();


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JButton btn = new JButton("Next");
    frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(btn);




    if(Global.epdi == 1){
        iFirstNum = rand.nextInt(11);
        iSecNum = rand.nextInt(11);
        iOperator = rand.nextInt(2);
    }else if(Global.epdi == 2){
        iFirstNum = rand.nextInt(11);
        iSecNum = rand.nextInt(11);
        iOperator = rand.nextInt(3);
    }else if(Global.epdi == 3){
        iFirstNum = rand.nextInt(20);
        iSecNum = rand.nextInt(11);
        iOperator = rand.nextInt(3);
    }else{
        iFirstNum = rand.nextInt(11);
        iSecNum = rand.nextInt(11);
        iOperator = rand.nextInt(2);

    }
    if(iOperator == 0){
        sOperator = "+";
        iCorResult = iFirstNum + iSecNum;
    }else if(iOperator == 1){
        sOperator = "-";
        iCorResult = iFirstNum - iSecNum;
    }else if(iOperator == 2){
        sOperator = "*";
        iCorResult = iFirstNum * iSecNum;
    }else{
        sOperator = "-----";
        iCorResult = 0;
    }
    firstNum.setText(String.valueOf(iFirstNum));
    operator.setText(sOperator);
    secNum.setText(String.valueOf(iSecNum));
    stableOperator.setText("=");
    slash.setText("/");
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();       

    if((oldResult != -500) && (flag == 1)){

        sResult = result.getText();
        iResult = Integer.parseInt(sResult);

        System.out.format("%d,%d\n",iResult,oldResult);
        if(iResult == oldResult){
            Global.correctAns++;
        }
        //result.setText("");

        oldResult = iCorResult;
        Global.allAns++;
    }else if(flag == 0) {

            oldResult = iCorResult;
            flag =1;
    }

    sCorAns = String.valueOf(Global.correctAns);
    sAllAns = String.valueOf(Global.allAns);
    corAnswer.setText(sCorAns);
    allAnswer.setText(sAllAns);
    if(Global.allAns == 10){
        Global.estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        System.out.format("%d\n", Global.estimatedTime);
        setVisible(false);
        seeResults seRes = new seeResults();
        seRes.setVisible(true);
    }

}                                    




private void nextKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                               

private void resultActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            new PrakseisGameGUI().setVisible(true);

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Please only post the relevant code and try to trim down the empty lines. Further, could you clearly indicate what is happening and what you expected to happen. Your question also gives the impression that you had a working version and after a little change it stopped working. Please indicate clearly what you changed when it stopped working

Comment: Sorry for this,but was my first post and i don;t really know how to do it write.Let me explain more my problem.I have a Jtextfield where i write a result inside.Then i want to press enter while my cursor is in the jtextfield,and activate a jbutton named next.I had to my constructor this command:"getRootPane().setDefaultButton(next);",and work well.After i change from desing the font from all the jbuttons and jlabels and then when i writting i jtextfield and press enter nothing happened.

Comment: @user2485610 you should edit your original question instead of providing details in the comments.

Comment: @user2485610 Don't post explanations in comments, edit your post instead. To write a proper example, provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). The link will give you advices on how to produce a good code example that will get you a fast and good answer.

Comment: I changed.How now look like?

Comment: @user2485610 Unfortunately this is not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). The code does not compile: `initComponents` is missing, `Global` and `next` are missing too and many other fields. Also, to notify somebody, use the '@username' (see comment help)

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Jtextfield where i write a result inside.Then i want to press enter while my cursor is in the jtextfield,and activate a jbutton named next.

Use the same ActionListener for the text field and the button.

```
ActionListener next = new ActionListener(...);
textField.addActionListener( next );
button.addActionListener( next );
```